# OpenMP recursion gets slower per thread

Tags: c, recursion, openmp

I am programming a little and very simple bruteforce program.
The idea was to have a master-thread, counting the first letter of a string and then they are completed to full passwords to compare it with the real password.

Thread 1: aaaaa to azzzz

Thread 2: baaaa to bzzzz

etc., when checking small letters only.

The completion is done with a recursive prozedure. The thread gets his first letter (a) and calls the procedure, building aaaaa, aaaab, aaaac, aaaad.. azzzy, azzzz.

The problem is, that the recursive procedure gets slower with each thread. My system is a quadcore CPU, but even running it with 2 threads slows down the procedure for 6 letters from around 20 seconds to 38 seconds and randomly even 1min 30 seconds.

I actually think it would be some issue with memory access, but I cannot find it.
The time is only measured for the procedure itself, so anything around it shouldn't interfere with it. The code looks probably a bit f*cked up, because I tried so many different things already, moved parts, inserted outputs for checks etc.. sorry for that.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <omp.h>

static void bruteForce(char* currentPW, int index, int PWLength, char* alphabet, int* alphabetSize);
char alphabet[] =   "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
                    "-+,;.:_!§$%&=*<>"
                    "0123456789";
int alphabetSize;
time_t gStartTime, gEndTime;
int omp_get_num_threads(void);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int PWLength = 9;
    int i = 0;
    int currentPWLength;
    omp_set_dynamic(0);     // Explicitly disable dynamic teams

    // Timer starten
    time( &gStartTime );

    for(currentPWLength = 6; currentPWLength <= PWLength; ++currentPWLength )
    {
        // Create teams
        #pragma omp parallel private(alphabetSize) num_threads(2)
        {
            alphabetSize = sizeof(alphabet) - 1;
            // We will copy the alphabet in our own memory, so there is no race condition
            char* threadAlphabet = malloc(sizeof(alphabet));
            strncpy(threadAlphabet, alphabet, alphabetSize);

            // Only one thread will do this
            #pragma omp single nowait
            for( i = 0; i < alphabetSize; ++i )
            {
                int j = 0;
                // We will store the startStrings in memory
                // This could be also done in an array, but at this point we do not need a
                // structure.
                char* startString = malloc(currentPWLength + 1);
                startString[0] = alphabet[i];
                for(j = 1; j <= currentPWLength; j++)
                    startString[j] = '\0';

                // At this point there will be 30 tasks to be solved.
                // Each team member can be assigned to a task.
                // This way we can split up the tasks to all members even in a single "Umgebung"
                // Note: Not NUMA friendly, but very fast as no new threads (HUGE overload!)
                //        have to be created
                #pragma omp task
                {
                    // Just some debug
                    printf("I am number %d and and my startString = %s\n", omp_get_thread_num(), startString);
                    double tOmpStartTime = omp_get_wtime();

                    // This will run the BruteForce algorithm
                    bruteForce(startString, 1, currentPWLength, &*threadAlphabet, &alphabetSize);

                    // More debug
                    double tOmpEndTime = omp_get_wtime();
                    double tDifTime = tOmpEndTime-tOmpStartTime;
                    printf("Number %d finished: Time: \t %f \n", omp_get_thread_num(), tDifTime);

                    // Give allocated memory free
                    free(startString);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Timer stoppen
    time( &gEndTime );
    printf("Elapsed time: %ds", gEndTime-gStartTime);

    puts( "!!! Passwort nicht gefunden !!!" );

    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

And the bruteforce procedure:

```
void bruteForce(char* currentPW, int index, int PWLength, char* alphabet, int* alphabetSize)
{
    // Loop through all letters to append them
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < *alphabetSize; ++i)
    {
        // Append
        currentPW[index] = alphabet[i];

        if (index == PWLength - 1)
        {
            static const char* gPW = "Aaa3b5";
            // We can not use strcmp function here, as it can cause memory race conditions.
            // Therefore an own version below.
            const unsigned char *p1 = (const unsigned char *)currentPW;
            const unsigned char *p2 = (const unsigned char *)gPW;
            int equal = 1;

            while (*p1 != '\0')
            {
                if (*p2 == '\0' || *p2 != *p1)
                {
                    equal = -1;
                    break;
                }
                p1++;
                p2++;
            }
            if (*p2 != '\0')
                equal = -1;

            else if(equal == 1)
            {
                // Password found
                // Print information and escape
                printf("Passwort = %s!\n", currentPW);
                // Timer stoppen
                time( &gEndTime );
                printf("Elapsed time: %ds\n", gEndTime-gStartTime);

                exit(0);
            }
        }
        // We haven't appent enough, increase index and run again
        else bruteForce(currentPW, index + 1, PWLength, alphabet, alphabetSize);
    }
}
```

Log with 1 thread:

```
Password length = 6
I am number 0 and have i = 0 and my startString = a
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 13 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 1 and my startString = b
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 2 and my startString = c
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 3 and my startString = d
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 4 and my startString = e
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 13 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 5 and my startString = f
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 6 and my startString = g
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 7 and my startString = h
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 8 and my startString = i
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 9 and my startString = j
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 10 and my startString = k
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 13 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 11 and my startString = l
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 12 and my startString = m
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 13 and my startString = n
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 14 and my startString = o
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 13 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 15 and my startString = p
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 16 and my startString = q
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 13 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 17 and my startString = r
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 18 and my startString = s
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 13 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 19 and my startString = t
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 20 and my startString = u
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 21 and my startString = v
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 22 and my startString = w
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 13 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 23 and my startString = x
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 24 and my startString = y
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 25 and my startString = z
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 13 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 26 and my startString = A
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 13 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 27 and my startString = B
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 28 and my startString = C
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 29 and my startString = D
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 13 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 30 and my startString = E
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 31 and my startString = F
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 32 and my startString = G
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 33 and my startString = H
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 13 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 34 and my startString = I
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 35 and my startString = J
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 36 and my startString = K
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 13 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 37 and my startString = L
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 38 and my startString = M
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 39 and my startString = N
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 40 and my startString = O
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 13 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 41 and my startString = P
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 42 and my startString = Q
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 43 and my startString = R
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 13 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 44 and my startString = S
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 45 and my startString = T
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 46 and my startString = U
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 47 and my startString = V
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 13 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 48 and my startString = W
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 49 and my startString = X
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 50 and my startString = Y
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 13 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 51 and my startString = Z
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 52 and my startString = -
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 53 and my startString = +
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 54 and my startString = ,
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 13 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 55 and my startString = ;
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 56 and my startString = .
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 13 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 57 and my startString = :
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 58 and my startString = _
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 59 and my startString = !
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 13 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 60 and my startString = ยบ
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 61 and my startString = $
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 62 and my startString = %
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 13 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 63 and my startString = &
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 64 and my startString = =
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 65 and my startString = *
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 66 and my startString = <
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 13 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 67 and my startString = >
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 68 and my startString = 0
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 69 and my startString = 1
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 70 and my startString = 2
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 71 and my startString = 3
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 13 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 72 and my startString = 4
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 73 and my startString = 5
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 74 and my startString = 6
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 75 and my startString = 7
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 0 and my startString = a
Number 0 finished: 15 minutes 51 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 1 and my startString = b
Number 0 finished: 16 minutes 42 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 2 and my startString = c
Number 0 finished: 16 minutes 43 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 3 and my startString = d
Number 0 finished: 15 minutes 56 seconds
```

Log with 4 threads:

```
Password length = 6
I am number 1 and have i = 0 and my startString = a
I am number 3 and have i = 3 and my startString = d
I am number 2 and have i = 2 and my startString = c
I am number 0 and have i = 1 and my startString = b
Number 1 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 1 and have i = 4 and my startString = e
Number 1 finished: 1 minutes 11 seconds
I am number 1 and have i = 5 and my startString = f
Number 0 finished: 2 minutes 3 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 6 and my startString = g
Number 3 finished: 2 minutes 16 seconds
I am number 3 and have i = 7 and my startString = h
Number 2 finished: 2 minutes 26 seconds
I am number 2 and have i = 8 and my startString = i
Number 1 finished: 1 minutes 11 seconds
I am number 1 and have i = 9 and my startString = j
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 38 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 10 and my startString = k
Number 3 finished: 0 minutes 51 seconds
I am number 3 and have i = 11 and my startString = l
Number 2 finished: 1 minutes 2 seconds
I am number 2 and have i = 12 and my startString = m
Number 2 finished: 0 minutes 30 seconds
I am number 2 and have i = 13 and my startString = n
Number 2 finished: 0 minutes 29 seconds
I am number 2 and have i = 14 and my startString = o
Number 0 finished: 1 minutes 51 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 15 and my startString = p
Number 1 finished: 2 minutes 8 seconds
I am number 1 and have i = 16 and my startString = q
Number 3 finished: 1 minutes 36 seconds
I am number 3 and have i = 17 and my startString = r
Number 3 finished: 0 minutes 26 seconds
I am number 3 and have i = 18 and my startString = s
Number 2 finished: 0 minutes 44 seconds
I am number 2 and have i = 19 and my startString = t
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 55 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 20 and my startString = u
Number 1 finished: 0 minutes 48 seconds
I am number 1 and have i = 21 and my startString = v
Number 2 finished: 1 minutes 10 seconds
I am number 2 and have i = 22 and my startString = w
Number 3 finished: 1 minutes 15 seconds
I am number 3 and have i = 23 and my startString = x
Number 3 finished: 0 minutes 29 seconds
I am number 3 and have i = 24 and my startString = y
Number 0 finished: 1 minutes 34 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 25 and my startString = z
Number 1 finished: 1 minutes 43 seconds
I am number 1 and have i = 26 and my startString = A
Number 2 finished: 0 minutes 56 seconds
I am number 2 and have i = 27 and my startString = B
Number 3 finished: 0 minutes 45 seconds
I am number 3 and have i = 28 and my startString = C
Number 3 finished: 0 minutes 31 seconds
I am number 3 and have i = 29 and my startString = D
Number 0 finished: 1 minutes 39 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 30 and my startString = E
Number 3 finished: 0 minutes 32 seconds
I am number 3 and have i = 31 and my startString = F
Number 2 finished: 1 minutes 37 seconds
I am number 2 and have i = 32 and my startString = G
Number 1 finished: 1 minutes 42 seconds
I am number 1 and have i = 33 and my startString = H
Number 1 finished: 0 minutes 30 seconds
I am number 1 and have i = 34 and my startString = I
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 47 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 35 and my startString = J
Number 3 finished: 0 minutes 57 seconds
I am number 3 and have i = 36 and my startString = K
Number 2 finished: 0 minutes 47 seconds
I am number 2 and have i = 37 and my startString = L
Number 1 finished: 1 minutes 33 seconds
I am number 1 and have i = 38 and my startString = M
Number 0 finished: 1 minutes 33 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 39 and my startString = N
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 40 and my startString = O
Number 2 finished: 1 minutes 39 seconds
I am number 2 and have i = 41 and my startString = P
Number 3 finished: 1 minutes 44 seconds
I am number 3 and have i = 42 and my startString = Q
Number 1 finished: 0 minutes 33 seconds
I am number 1 and have i = 43 and my startString = R
Number 1 finished: 0 minutes 28 seconds
I am number 1 and have i = 44 and my startString = S
Number 0 finished: 1 minutes 7 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 45 and my startString = T
Number 1 finished: 0 minutes 29 seconds
I am number 1 and have i = 46 and my startString = U
Number 3 finished: 1 minutes 6 seconds
I am number 3 and have i = 47 and my startString = V
Number 2 finished: 1 minutes 12 seconds
I am number 2 and have i = 48 and my startString = W
Number 2 finished: 0 minutes 21 seconds
I am number 2 and have i = 49 and my startString = X
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 45 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 50 and my startString = Y
Number 2 finished: 0 minutes 41 seconds
I am number 2 and have i = 51 and my startString = Z
Number 1 finished: 1 minutes 11 seconds
I am number 1 and have i = 52 and my startString = -
Number 3 finished: 1 minutes 11 seconds
I am number 3 and have i = 53 and my startString = +
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 59 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 54 and my startString = ,
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 28 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 55 and my startString = ;
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 28 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 56 and my startString = .
Number 3 finished: 1 minutes 25 seconds
I am number 3 and have i = 57 and my startString = :
Number 2 finished: 1 minutes 38 seconds
I am number 2 and have i = 58 and my startString = _
Number 1 finished: 1 minutes 36 seconds
I am number 1 and have i = 59 and my startString = !
Number 1 finished: 0 minutes 29 seconds
I am number 1 and have i = 60 and my startString = º
Number 0 finished: 1 minutes 6 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 61 and my startString = $
Number 1 finished: 0 minutes 35 seconds
I am number 1 and have i = 62 and my startString = %
Number 3 finished: 1 minutes 26 seconds
I am number 3 and have i = 63 and my startString = &
Number 2 finished: 1 minutes 20 seconds
I am number 2 and have i = 64 and my startString = =
Number 2 finished: 0 minutes 20 seconds
I am number 2 and have i = 65 and my startString = *
Number 0 finished: 0 minutes 48 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 66 and my startString = <
Number 1 finished: 0 minutes 55 seconds
I am number 1 and have i = 67 and my startString = >
Number 3 finished: 0 minutes 47 seconds
Password length = 7
I am number 2 and have i = 0 and my startString = a
I am number 3 and have i = 1 and my startString = b
I am number 1 and have i = 2 and my startString = c
I am number 0 and have i = 3 and my startString = d
Number 0 finished: 26 minutes 32 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 4 and my startString = e
Number 0 finished: 25 minutes 50 seconds
I am number 0 and have i = 5 and my startString = f
Number 2 finished: 54 minutes 8 seconds
I am number 2 and have i = 6 and my startString = g
Number 3 finished: 72 minutes 27 seconds
I am number 3 and have i = 7 and my startString = h
Number 1 finished: 75 minutes 45 seconds
I am number 1 and have i = 8 and my startString = i
Number 0 finished: 53 minutes 6 seconds
```

Edit: I have updated my code and moved all variables from global to thread-memory. Actually i was hoping to solve my problem this way, as I thought it would be some kind of race condition. But it will still take randomly over 1 minute instead of under 20 seconds. :-(, thought it feels more "stable" now!

Comment: Welcome to the world of parallel programming, where nothing is ever as you expect it to be :)

Comment: I am afraid my lecturer will not accept this answer.
Or did you want to say that I did not make any mistake there?

Comment: can you post the timings (total walltime) for each number of threads?

Comment: @steabert: I will post the output for a run with PasswordLength = 6 this evening with 1,2 and 4 threads, if it is what you were asking for.

Comment: Edited two logs, with one thread and with four threads. Note that I had bug there, thus it counted only to 7 not 9 (wayne).

As you can see for one thread the needed time is nearly identic, but for four threads in about 50% way higher.

Comment: can you match the posted code with what you actually ran? then people can run it themselves and compare properly.

Comment: Actually the whole code is in my first post. To change the number of threads to run with, just change the value "num_threads(1)" in line 28. The code was build with Codeblocks, it didn't use any special compiler-values.

Comment: I have still no idea what could be wrong :/

Comment: Always time OpenMP programs with `omp_get_wtime`.  SO is littered with questions arising from a misunderstanding of what other timing routines measure.  I'm not saying that this is the cause of your problem, just that it is one potential source of error to eliminate.

Comment: @Workoverflow "*The code was build with Codeblocks, it didn't use any special compiler-values.*" Ummm I don't know any compiler that supports OpenMP implicitly. You always have to enable it via some flag/switch. And the only thing I see done i parallel is some copying. You make a thread team, just to execute 3 lines of code, and then you go into `single`. I probably missed something though, because the code is just two walls of text and all is done in `main`. It's quite hard to read.

Comment: @luk32 I guess you got it wrong. I rewrote it according to this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065943/task-based-programming-pragma-omp-task-versus-pragma-omp-parallel-for
It will create teams in the parallel region, then the master thread will build the startstrings and create tasks for them. All threads can be assigned to tasks and therefore it (the BruteForce-Algorithm) is computed with all threads.

And I set Codeblocks up for openmp using this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p0woqF2XCeg
adding -fopenmp to linker and using mingw with libgomp-1.dll.

Comment: @Workoverflow Well, as I said I did misread it. I ran your code, and can't reproduce the results. I compiled it with `gcc -O3 -fopenmp` and got stable results. [Code](https://gist.github.com/luk32/960783ef118b9deced93), [results](https://gist.github.com/luk32/97e31cda8b41a4870a69). This was done on 2-core Debian VM. Maybe it is related to memory locality after all. Oh, btw using one thread also is faster, but no so much. It says it took abt 5.7s.

Comment: About 7 seconds to test one range of 6 letters? What hardware did you use? Maybe should I try it with linux too, I have a Mint 17 installed. Anyway it is very strange that your results are stable, on the other hand it disburdens me.

Comment: The times were comparable to yours with out optimizations. They still seemed stable. It's a debian virtual machine running on virtual box hosted on win7 on a PC with core i7 920 (pretty old) with quite a lot of ram (24GBs). It has dedicated 2 cores with virtualization support enabled. I think it's the optimization, you can add the `-O3` flag next to `-fopenmp` too.

Comment: This is weird, your i7 920 should be slower than my i5 2500k and its memory clock is 1066 versus 1333 me. o_O
The optimization did not do the trick for me, I will just try on linux and let you know.

Comment: F*ck that. Just compiled and run it on debian with gcc 4.7 and libgomp1 (actually same like on windows) and got STABLE results. Thank you so much luk32. I would give you a thumb up, if you tell me how, for comments. Or write an answer! Conclusion: Don't waste 100 hours on windows for fixing a non existing bug, just use linux.